# nonlinear of system of differential equations

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I want to sketch the phase portrait of a planar system having
 i) a trajectory Γ with α(Γ)=ω(Γ)={x₀}, but Γ≠{x₀}.
ii) a trajectory Γ such  that ω(Γ) consist of one limit orbit and one equilibrium point.

I know that  a point p ∈ E is an ω-limit point of the trajectory  ϕ(. ,x) of the system x ̇=f(x) if there s a sequence tn→ ∞ such that
 lim┬(n-→∞)⁡〖ϕ(tn,x) 〗=p.
Similarly, if there is a sequence tn→ -∞ such that 
 lim┬(n-→∞)⁡〖ϕ(tn,x) 〗=q,
 and the point q ∈ , then the point q is called an α-limit point of the trajectory ϕ(.,x) of the system x ̇=f(x). 
but i could not know how to use that.

Comment: (i).  Any homoclinic orbit.
(ii).  Are you sure?  What about the Poincare-Bendixson theorem?

Comment: We haven't studied that theorem yet :(

Comment: I mean... I could be wrong.